# Microsoft Access Form default filter not passed but working

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have an existing ms access application. The Access application contains a summary list that is data driven and when you double click the row, it opens an Entry form. In the Entry form, it searches for the drilled down record and displays the previously selected item from the Summary screen on the Entry Form's Form_Open.

However, there was no code where the parameter for the primary key was passed when doing `DoCmd.OpenForm`. There was no filter or whereCondition when the query was being selected in the 
`DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0).OpenRecordset("TableName", dbOpenDynaset)`.

I am not familiar with Ms Access, where was the parameter being passed automatically?

Comment: First, check the Doubleclick event on the first form.  If it is a macro screenshot it, if it is VBA code copy and paste it into your post please.

Comment: There is nothing being passed "Automatically" - we just need to find where it is. Where you are double clicking - open that form/whatever it is in design view. Right click on whatever you normally double left click in Form View, and select `Properties` -> `Event` -> `OnDblClick` -> Look for `[Event Procedure]` and click the little `...` icon if it exists.

Comment: @Animate I think this has something to do with bounded values, if there is a bounded value in the previous screen, then it may be linked to the next edit screen via a bounded value again?